# Teradata connection issue with ODBC driver

Tags: python, odbc, teradata

Trying to make connection to teradata using ODBC method and using below code but it giving error like "**teradata.api.DatabaseError: (0, '[I] [. Check that the ODBC driver is installed and the ODBCINI or ODBCINST environment variables are correctly set.')**"

ODBCINI & ODBCINST Path are set as

ODBCINI= /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/odbc.ini
ODBCINST = /opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/odbcinst.ini

```
import teradata
import pandas as pd


host,username,password = 'xxxxx','xxxxx', 'xxxxx'

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec ("Teradata_ODBC_DSN")
with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system=host, username=username,
                            password=password) as connect:
        query = "SELECT 1;"
        df = pd.read_sql(query,connect)
        print(df.head())
```

**udaexec.ini**

```
# Application Configuration
[CONFIG]
appName=HelloWorld
version=0.1
logConsole=True
dataSourceName=Teradata_ODBC_DSN
table=DBC.DBCInfo

# Default Data Source Configuration
[DEFAULT]
method=odbc
charset=UTF8
authentication=LDAP

# Data Source Definition
[Teradata_ODBC_DSN]
system=hostname
username=xxxx
password=xxxx
```

where I am doing wrong or its problem with configuration of ODBC driver?

Comment: Teradata recommends that new applications use the `teradatasql` package (which does not rely on an external ODBC driver) rather than `teradata`. But if you want to figure out what's wrong here, double check the UdaExec logs and the contents of the ODBCINST and ODBCINI files. Note that you are not using anything from the udaexec.ini file except for the first 3 parameters in the [CONFIG] section.

Comment: Using teradatasql module able to connect.